# how to handle callback using kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines

the following snippet returns the result as 'null' on sequential code flow. I understand coroutines could be a viable solution to handle the callback asynchronously.

```
    fun getUserProperty(path: String): String? {
        var result: String? = null
        database.child(KEY_USERS).child(getUid()).child(path)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error: $error")
                }

                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "value: ${snapshot.value}")
                    result = snapshot.value.toString()
                }
            })
        return result
    }
```

Can the coroutines be of any help in this scenario to wait until the result of the callbacks (onDataChange()/onCancelled())?

Answer (score 11):

Since the Firebase Realtime Database SDK doesn't provide any suspend functions, coroutines are not helpful when dealing with its APIs.  You would need to convert the callback into a suspend function in order for you to be able to await the result in a coroutine.

Here's a suspend extension function that does this (I [discovered a solution](https://gist.github.com/Sloy/f68921a2ead6466e530ff4b18c180c4d) it by doing a google search):

```
suspend fun DatabaseReference.getValue(): DataSnapshot {
    return async(CommonPool) {
        suspendCoroutine<DataSnapshot> { continuation ->
            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(FValueEventListener(
                    onDataChange = { continuation.resume(it) },
                    onError = { continuation.resumeWithException(it.toException()) }
            ))
        }
    }.await()
}

class FValueEventListener(val onDataChange: (DataSnapshot) -> Unit, val onError: (DatabaseError) -> Unit) : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) = onDataChange.invoke(data)
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) = onError.invoke(error)
}
```

With this, you now how a `getValue()` suspect method on DatabaseReference that can be awaited in a coroutine.

Comment: Doug, thanks for inputs. Yes, came across a few similar approaches. Was wondering how the usage(referring the node in DB, receiving values) works?
https://gist.github.com/beyondeye/f69ba427938f79801c291d18131ff1d9

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The above snippet isn't sure how to call and return value from getValue(). Was looking for deep-dived articles to understand better.

Comment: Is there any reason `async` is unable in kotlin? Could only find `GlobalScope.async`.

Answer (score 5):

The **@Doug** example for singleValueEvent if you want to keep listing you can use **[coroutine flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html)** like below:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <reified T> DatabaseReference.listen(): Flow<DataResult<T?>> =
  callbackFlow {
    val valueListener = object : ValueEventListener {
      override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        close(databaseError.toException())
      }

      override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        try {
          val value = dataSnapshot.getValue(T::class.java)
          offer(DataResult.Success(value))
        } catch (exp: Exception) {
          Timber.e(exp)
          if (!isClosedForSend) offer(DataResult.Error(exp))
        }
      }
    }
    addValueEventListener(valueListener)

    awaitClose { removeEventListener(valueListener) }
  }
```

Comment: Do we have to have `awaitClose`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Yes

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still uses the original answer's code but needs to update it to match the non-experimental version of `Coroutines` here's how I changed it:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

suspend fun DatabaseReference.getSnapshotValue(): DataSnapshot {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suspendCoroutine<DataSnapshot> { continuation ->
            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(FValueEventListener(
                onDataChange = { continuation.resume(it) },
                onError = { continuation.resumeWithException(it.toException()) }
            ))
        }
    }
}

class FValueEventListener(val onDataChange: (DataSnapshot) -> Unit, val onError: (DatabaseError) -> Unit) : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) = onDataChange.invoke(data)
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) = onError.invoke(error)
}
```

Then using it would be as simple as: `val snapshot = ref.getSnapshotValue()`

**Update**

I also needed to observe a node and used Omar's answer to do it. If anyone needs an example of how to use it here it is:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <reified T> DatabaseReference.listen(): Flow<T?>? =
callbackFlow {
    val valueListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            close()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            try {
                val value = dataSnapshot.getValue(T::class.java)
                offer(value)
            } catch (exp: Exception) {
                if (!isClosedForSend) offer(null)
            }
        }
    }
    addValueEventListener(valueListener)
    awaitClose { removeEventListener(valueListener) }
}
```

Then to call it inside an Activity or Fragment you would create your listener like so:

```
var listener =  FirebaseUtils.databaseReference
   .child(AppConstants.FIREBASE_PATH_EMPLOYEES)
   .child(AuthUtils.retrieveUID()!!).listen<User>()
```

Then call it inside your function:

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
    withContext(IO) {
        listener?.collect{
            print(it)
        }
    }
}
```

And then dispose inside `onStop()`:

```
override fun onStop(){
    listener = null
    super.onStop()
}
```

Comment: Why do you need both `CoroutineScope(IO)` and `withContext(IO)`?

Comment: I had to do that because I'm not using the ViewModel  library.. I habe another coroutine I need to work with this so you can remove withContext I think